# Append rect after closing tag

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have array of rects and would like to mark one rect with another rect.

```js
chart.rect
        .filter(function(d){
          return d.today != undefined
        })
        .append("rect")
        .attr('width', function (d) { return "100px"; })
        .attr('height', function (d) { return "100px"; })
        .attr('x', function (d) { return 5; })
        .attr('y', function (d) { return 5; })
        .attr('fill', function (d) { return "yellow"; });
```

but the rect appear in the other rect:

```xml
<rect width="1%" height="100%" stroke-width="1" stroke="black" x="3%" fill="green">
   <rect width="100px" height="100px" x="5" y="5" fill="yellow"></rect>
</rect>
```

does anyone have an idea, how a element can add after the closing tag?

Comment: append means it gets inserted into the element, you would need something like [insertAfter](https://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access a selected node's parent node, and append the new `rect` to that.

Without having tested it, something likes this should work:

```
chart.rect
  .filter(function(d){
    return d.today != undefined
  }).each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this.parentNode)      
      .append("rect")
      .datum(d)
      .attr('width', function (d) { return "100px"; })
      .attr('height', function (d) { return "100px"; })
      .attr('x', function (d) { return 5; })
      .attr('y', function (d) { return 5; })
      .attr('fill', function (d) { return "yellow"; });
  })
```

This will append a yellow `rect` for each node that fulfills the filter criteria.

To position the yellow `rect` you have two options:

1. Position the yellow `rect` similarly to the way you position the original `rect` elements.
2. Alternatively, you can nest every of the original `rect` elements in each own `g`, and then position the `g` elements. Then you don't need to position related `rect` elements individually.

Hope this helps!